ComboBox Selection Not Updating Properly in UserControl (WPF) - SelectionChanged Event Fires but Value Doesn't Reflect Change
I am facing an issue where a ComboBox inside a UserControl does not update its selected value when an item is clicked from the dropdown. Interestingly, the Value property is updated, and the PropertyChanged event is triggered, but only when the ComboBox has focus and the mouse wheel is scrolled. This behavior is distinct from selecting an item from the dropdown, where the ComboBox_SelectionChanged event does not fire, the Value property is not updated, the PropertyChanged event is not triggered, and the UI display does not change to reflect the selected item.

Code Example
EnumPort.xaml.cs:
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace NodeVideoEffects.Control
{
    public partial class EnumPort : UserControl, IControl
    {
        int value = 0;
        public EnumPort(List<string> items)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            box.ItemsSource = items;
            Value = value;
        }

        public object? Value
        {
            get => value;
            set
            {
                this.value = (int?)value ?? 0;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Value = box.SelectedIndex;
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

EnumPort.xaml:
<UserControl x:Class="NodeVideoEffects.Control.EnumPort"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NodeVideoEffects.Control"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="box" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>


Issue:

When selecting an item from the dropdown, the Value property is not updated.
The ComboBox_SelectionChanged event does not fire.
The Value property is updated, and the PropertyChanged event fires, but only when the ComboBox is focused and the mouse wheel is used.
The UI display does not change to reflect the selected item from the dropdown.


The code for this ComboBox is available on GitHub: EnumPort.xaml.cs on GitHub

Request for Help:
Can anyone help with why the ComboBox selection is not updating correctly, and how to resolve this issue? Is there something wrong with the way the Value is being set or with the PropertyChanged event?
I set up the SelectionChanged event handler to respond to changes, expecting the displayed selected item in the dropdown to update and the event to fire accordingly. However, the SelectionChanged event does not fire, the displayed item does not change, and the Value property does not reflect the correct index when an item is selected from the dropdown. Could this be due to the way the Value property is implemented or some binding issue I might be overlooking?

It's nice you posted a github url. I looked-up the IControl interface. You implemented the PropertyChangedEventHandler but you didn't added the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on it.
You should extend your IControl(or class EnumPort) interface with INotifyPropertyChanged:
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace NodeVideoEffects.Control
{
    public interface IControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        object? Value { get; set; }
    }
}


Thank you. That might be a good idea. I will apply it to my code. However, this was not related to solving the issue.
